# Django - Displaying result information while optimizing database queries with models that multiple foreign key relationships

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship, django-queryset, database-optimization

So I'm trying to put together a webpage and I am currently have trouble putting together a results page for each user in the web application I am putting together.

Here are what my models look like:

```
class Fault(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    severity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=False, blank=False)
    recommendation = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=False, blank=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(_('date added'), default=timezone.now)
    ...


class FaultInstance(models.Model):
    auto = models.ForeignKey(Auto)
    fault = models.ForeignKey(Fault)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(_('date added'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = FaultInstanceManager()
    ...

class Auto(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    ...
```

I don't know if my model relationships are ideal, however it made sense it my head.  So each user can have multiple *Auto* objects associated to them.  And each *Auto* can have multiple *FaultInstance* objects associated to it.

In the results page, I want to list out the all the *FaultInstances* that a user has across their *Autos*. And under each listed *FaultInstance* I will have a list of all the autos that the user owns that has the fault, with its information (here is kind of what I had in mind).

**All *FaultInstance* Listing Ordered by Severity (large number to low number)**

```
FaultInstance:
   FaultDescription:
   FaultRecommendation:
   ListofAutosWithFault:
       AutoLabel AutoModel AutoYear ...
       AutoLabel AutoModel AutoYear ...
```

Obviously, do things the correct way would mean that I want to do as much of the list creation in the Python/Django side of things and avoid doing any logic or processing in the template.  I am able to create a list per severity with the a model manager as seen here:

```
class FaultInstanceManager(models.Manager):
    def get_faults_by_user_severity(self, user, severity):
        faults = defaultdict(list)
        qs_faultinst = self.model.objects.select_related().filter(
                auto__user=user, fault__severity=severity
            ).order_by('auto__make')
        for result in qs_faultinst:
            faults[result.fault].append(result)

        faults.default_factory = None
        return faults
```

I still need to specify each severity but I guess if I only have 5 severity levels, I can create a list for each severity level and pass each individual one to template.  Any suggestions for this is appreciated.  However, thats not my problem.  My stopping point right now is that I want to create a summary table at the top of their report which can give the user breakdown of fault instances per make|model|year.  I can't think of the proper query or data structure to pass on to the template.

**Summary** (table of all the *FaultInstances* with the following column headers):

```
FaultInstance    Make|Model|Year    NumberOfAutosAffected
```

This will let me know metrics for a make or a model or a year (in the example below, its separating faults based on model).  I'm listing *FaultInstances* because I'm only listed *Faults* that a connected to a user.

**For Example**

```
Bad Starter     Nissan     1
Bad Tailight    Honda      2
Bad Tailight    Nissan     1
```

And I am such a perfectionist that I want to do this while optimizing database queries.  If I can create a data structure in my original query that will be easily parsed in template and still get both these sections in my report (maybe a defaultdict of a defaultdict(list)), thats what I want to do.  Thanks for the help and hopefully my question is thorough and makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense to use *related names* because it simplifies your query. Like this:

```
class FaultInstance(models.Model):
    auto = models.ForeignKey(Auto, related_name='fault_instances')
    fault = models.ForeignKey(Fault, related_name='fault_instances')
    ...

class Auto(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='autos')
```

In this case you can use:

```
qs_faultinst = user.fault_instances.filter(fault__severity=severity).order_by('auto__make')
```

instead of:

```
qs_faultinst = self.model.objects.select_related().filter(
                auto__user=user, fault__severity=severity
            ).order_by('auto__make')
```

I can't figure out your summary table, may be you meant:

```
Fault    Make|Model|Year    NumberOfAutosAffected
```

In this case you can use [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/). But It (grouping) would still be slow if you have enough data. The one easy solution is just to denormalize data by creating extra model and create few [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) to update it or you can use cache.

If you have a predefined set of *severities* then think about this:

```
class Fault(models.Model):

    SEVERITY_LOW = 0
    SEVERITY_MIDDLE = 1
    SEVERITY_HIGH = 2
    ...
    SEVERITY_CHOICES = (
        (SEVERITY_LOW, 'Low'),
        (SEVERITY_MIDDLE, 'Middle'),
        (SEVERITY_HIGH, 'High'),
        ...
    )
    ...
    severity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=SEVERITY_LOW,
                                                choices=SEVERITY_CHOICES)
    ...
```

In your templates you can just iterate through Fault.SEVERITY_CHOICES.

**Update:**

Change your models:

*Аllocate* model into a separate model:

```
class AutoModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

*Change* the field model of model Auto :

```
class Auto(models.Model):
    ...
    auto_model = models.ForeignKey(AutoModel, related_name='cars')
    ...
```

*Add* a model:

```
class MyDenormalizedModelForReport(models.Model):

    fault = models.ForeignKey(Fault, related_name='reports')
    auto_model = models.ForeignKey(AutoModel, related_name='reports')
    year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
    number_of_auto_affected = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

*Add* a signal:

```
def update_denormalized_model(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        rep, dummy_created = MyDenormalizedModelForReport.objects.get_or_create(fault=instance.fault, auto_model=instance.auto.auto_model, year=instance.auto.year)
        rep.number_of_auto_affected += 1
        rep.save()

post_save.connect(update_denormalized_model, sender=FaultInstance)
```

Comment: I added a bit more information about my summary table.  I like your suggestion for my severities.  However, I don't quite understand your suggestions for denormalizing the data and using signals.  Can you point me to a better example?

Comment: Thanks Andrey for the further explanation.  I marked your answer as correct and thanks once again!